# JS onClick return false and jQuery global .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm debugging my library in someone else's code: Part of it it's vanilla JS and my library is written in jQuery. It have tabs [tabber.js](http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/) (code from 2006) and it have tabs `onclick` event attached to DOM that call `return false`.

```
tabberObj.prototype.init = function(e)
{
    DOM_a = document.createElement("a") ;

    DOM_a.appendChild( document.createTextNode( t.headingText ) ) ;
    DOM_a.href = "javascript:void(null);" ;
    DOM_a.title = t.headingText ;
    DOM_a.onclick = this.navClick ;
    ...
};


tabberObj.prototype.navClick = function(event)
{
   ...
   return false;
};
```

[Here is tab code](http://alessandrorosa.altervista.org/complex/code/js/all.projects/basics/tabber.js) where there's click handler (line 311 and 265).

In my library I have:

```
$(document).bind('click.terminal', function(e) {
    var sender = $(e.target);
    if (!sender.closest('.terminal').hasClass('terminal') &&
        settings.onBlur(self) !== false) {
        self.disable();
    }
});
```

Will my code fire? Does return false in JS do same thing as in jQuery. Will replacing return false by `event.preventDefault()` will make my code to run?

From symptoms it look like my function was not executed. I've try to fetch whole app using `wget` but it didn't run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...and it have tabs onclick event attached to DOM that call return false.
>
> ... will my code fire or return false will stopPropagate like jQuery does.

If you mean that the tabs have `onclick` attributes on them:

```
<div onclick="return someFunction();">...</div>
```

(note you need the `return` **in** the attribute), or that they get a handler assigned to the reflected property for that:

```
someElementReference.onclick = someFunction;
```

...then doing `return false` in that handler will prevent the default action of the click but will not stop propagation. More (on my blog): [*The story on `return false`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html)

Note, though, that the order in which old DOM0-style handlers (like the above) are fired relative to DOM2-style handlers like the ones jQuery adds **is undefined**. Some browsers fire the DOM0 handlers first, then the DOM2 handlers; others do it the other way around. It doesn't really matter in your case since you're not doing anything to stop propagation (and in particular, nothing to stop *immediate* propagation to other handlers on the same element), but it still seemed worth calling out.

Comment: It's not onclick attribute but onclick DOM property.

Comment: @jcubic: It's the same answer either way, they work the same way.